# Why do I keep getting this error in R studio? Error in accuracy.default(fitdamp) : No accuracy method found for an object of class mdl_d

Tags: r, forecasting

I keep getting these errors, I need to run accuracy to get the

ME  RMSE   MAE   MPE  MAPE  MASE RMSSE  ACF1

Here are the libraries I have loaded:

```
library(fpp3)
library(tsibble) # For handling time series data
library(forecast)
library(stats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibbledata)
```

> "Error in accuracy.default(fitdamp) :  No accuracy method found for an object of class mdl_d"

```
fitdamp <- tsibbledrugsalesdata |>
  model(
SES = ETS(Sales ~ error("A") + trend("Ad") + season("N"))
  )
tidy(fitdamp)
fitdamp |>
  forecast(h=24) |>
  autoplot(tsibbledrugsalesdata) +
  labs(x = "Hundreds of Thousands", y = "Sales",
       title = 
         "Australian drug sales, Holt's damped method")

accuracy(fitdamp)
```

At first I thought it was my libraries masking the accuracy() function so I tried detaching 'forecast' and 'fable', still does not work.

This code is similar to the code from my forecasting lecture so I don't know why its not working for me or if I wrote the code incorrectly.

Thanks guys

Comment: The code doesn't assign the result of `tidy(fitdamp)` to a variable. Should it be `fitdamp <- tidy(fitdamp)` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Happy Taco Resort! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start here!), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are doing just loading `fpp3` is enough since it imports the the `accuracy()` from `fabletools`,the one you need which uses `accuracy.mdl_df()` , and other necessary packages for your code (`fable`, `fabletools`, etc. Just check `fpp3::fpp3_packages()`)  .

No need to load the other packages since as you suspect, it's a conflict between packages. You either start with a new R session or explicitly call the `accuracy()` you need.

```
fabletools::accuracy(fitdamp)
```

Comment: thank you derf, I hope you see this I am new to StackOverflow and not sure on how it works yet!

Comment: @HappyTacoResort You're welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you get the solution ?